# Android - cross-platform friendly debug/logger macro

Tags: android, c++, ios, debugging, macros

I am building C++ code that is used on both android and iOS. I need some form of debugger macro to insert debugging easily into the code.
For example, I was thinking of something like this:

```
#ifdef ANDROID 
#   define MY_DEBUG(debugmsg) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, ANDROID_DEBUG_TAG,debugmsg)
#   define MY_DEBUG(debugmsg, mystr)    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, ANDROID_DEBUG_TAG,debugmsg,mystr)
#elif defined (iOS)
#   define MY_DEBUG(debugmsg) printf(debugmsg)
#   define MY_DEBUG(debugmsg, mystr)    printf(debugmsg, mystr)
#endif
```

So for example I could use MY_DEBUG("hello %s","world") and MY_DEBUG("hello")

However it complains about macro redefinition (and rightfully so). How do I make a macro.. 'overload', or accept more than one parameter if entered?

Also - does printf() send data to the iOS console?

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload macros the way you can with functions because the preprocessor has not changed significantly, if at all, since C.  A common approach is to use MY_DEBUG and MY_DEBUG2 etc.

There are [variatic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) but I avoid them in multi-platform code.

Comment: I see. Is there a reason why you avoid them in multiplatform code? Any specifics for Android/iOS?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan I have the unfortunate pleasure of having to work with some older crappy tools so I try to avoid "newer" features from C99.  Variadic macros should be fine on Android and iOS, but I have never tried.